# print recursive pattern without quotes in python

Tags: python-3.x

my code for pattern:

```
def pattern(n):
    if n==1:
        return '1'
    else:
        return pattern(n-int(n/2))*2+str(n)
    print(pattern(n))
```

> i need:

```
>>> pattern(1)
1
>>> pattern(2)
112
>>> pattern(4)
1121124
>>> pattern(8)
112112411211248
```

but i get:

```
>>> pattern(1)
'1'
>>> pattern(2)
'112'
>>> pattern(4)
'1121124'
>>> pattern(8)
'112112411211248'
```

i have tried a lot but nothing is working to get rid of those pesky quotes.

Comment: Just do `print(pattern(8))`

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are from the REPL printing the representation of the result of the function call, which is a string. If you do not want the representation then just print the result explicitly instead.

Comment: i can print it explicitly but when i do my output becomes a a series of None with only explicitly stated integers being printed correctly